# Heteroscedasticity-consistent F-test

Tags: r, regression, heteroscedasticity, f-test

Why is the F-test for overall significance (OLS regression analysis) invalid when residuals are heteroscedastic? 
Is there a way to calculate it in a consistent way under heteroscedasticity?
Is there any function in R to accomplish that?

Comment: I think it can be calculated in R through waldtest function. Example: `waldtest(model_restricted, model_unrestricted, vcov=vcovHC(model_unrestricted))` Is it correct?

Comment: About the invalidity of the test, the Wooldridge (Introductory Econometrics, 2nd edition, p. 253) says: _"If heteroskedasticity is present, this version of the [F] test is invalid. The heteroskedasticity-robust version has no simple form, but it can be computed using certain statistical packages."_ And the mystery continues!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the F-statistic formula from Hayashi:

$F=\frac{\left(Rb-r\right)^T\left[R\left(X^T X\right)^{-1}R^T\right]^{-1}\left(Rb-r\right)/ \rho}{s^2}$

(notation: we're testing the hypothesis $R\beta = r$, $R\in\mathbb{R}^{\rho\times K}$, rank($R$)=$\rho$, $s^2$ is the variance of the error term)

We can immediately see why this won't apply to the heteroskedastic case--in particular, we definitely don't expect $s^2$ to be a constant.

Intuitively, we know there's a (nontrivial) relationship between $t$ and $F$ statistics--so given that $t$ statistics are heteroskedasticity-dependent, we should expect $F$-statistics to be so as well.

See [here](http://www3.grips.ac.jp/~yamanota/Lecture_Note_9_Heteroskedasticity.pdf) (pp 3-4) for why the Wald test you suggested is correct & hence the `waldtest` function in R is appropriate.